# Delete TreeViewItem with Delete Button

Tags: c#, wpf, keypress, treeviewitem

I want to be able to delete child nodes from a `TreeViewItem` by pressing the delete button on the keyboard. I'm using a `SelectedItem` to try to do this.

Currently I am using a `KeyDown` event in my code-behind:

```
private void Tree_One_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Delete)
        class.deleteNodeOnKeyPress();
}
```

From there my program calls to a function that should perform the delete operation:

```
public static void deleteNodeOnKeyPress()
{
    Tree.Items.Remove(Tree.SelectedItem);
}
```

This is what I've tried, and for the life of me I don't know why it doesn't work. I've had trouble with the `keyPress` events before. Maybe someone can point me in the right direction.

Let me know if you need any more code!

**UPDATES:** I am now using `e.Key == Key.Delete`, still does not affect any change.

Here are the compiler errors after trying `Tree.Items.Remove(Tree.SelectedItem);`

1. `The property or indexer 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<System...TreeViewItem>.Items' cannot be used in this context because the get accessor is inaccessible`
2. `'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<System...TreeViewItem>.Items' is inaccessible due to its protection level`
3. `'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<System...TreeViewItem>' does not contain a definition for 'SelectedItem' and no extension method 'SelectedItem' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<System...TreeViewItem>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Answer (score 1):

```
    function detectspecialkeys(e) {
         var evtobj = window.event ? event : e
         if (evtobj.altKey || evtobj.ctrlKey || evtobj.shiftKey)
             alert("you pressed one of the 'Alt', 'Ctrl', or 'Shift' keys")
     }
             document.onkeyup = detectspecialkeys
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is rather old, but I came across it while attempting to to do the same thing (delete a TreeView node upon detecting user pressing the Delete key). Not sure why you are trying to delete from the Items collection, but deleting the SelectedNode from the Nodes collection should work fine. One thing not mentioned is that the SelectedItem (or SelectedNode) can be null so you will probably want to test for that.

```
private void Tree_One_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
    {
        if (Tree.SelectedNode != null)
        {
            Tree.Nodes.Remove(Tree.SelectedNode);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the real problem is with `Tree.Remove(SelectedItem);`. I would recommend doing `treeView1.Items.Remove(treeView1.SelectedItem);` where treeView1 is your `TreeView` control.

Comment: I've switched it and updated my code. The node still does not delete from the Tree.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? Did it even enter the KeyDown function?

Comment: Yep, it goes right through both functions, but the node stays put.

Comment: Does `deleteNodeOnKeyPress` have to be static? I think your code would be cleaner if it wasn't as you can change `class.deleteNodeOnKeyPress()` to just `deleteNodeOnKeyPress()`

Comment: Also, what is `SelectedItem`? Is it an object you defined somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, for some reason `deleteNodeOnKeyPress` has to be static or it won't compile. It probably can't access `SelectedItem` without being static. `SelectedItem` is defined when the `TreeView`'s `SelectedItemChanged()` function is called. It is sent to the other class as a `TreeViewItem`.

Comment: Why don't you try `treeView1.Items.Remove(treeView1.SelectedItem);` where treeView1 is your TreeView?

Comment: When I try that I get three compiler errors, I'll put them in my question.